# How to get a list of songs, artists, albums on WP7 devices?

Tags: windows-phone-7

I want to create a simple audio player for Windows Phone 7.
How can I get a list of songs, artists, albums, genres and method to play item which i selected ? something like is in native wp7 app "Music+Videos"

second problem: 
I downloaded "Music + Videos Hub Sample" from [Code samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff431744%28VS.92%29.aspx#BKMK_Media), I execute this project and it play some song, display title and coverart of song BUT...
when I copy this code, add references etc to my project then not display coverart and display title of song, why?

Where i can find more samples of media player for wp7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [MediaLibrary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx) to access the songs, artists and albums on the user's device.

```
using(MediaLibrary library = new MediaLibrary())
{
     SongCollection songs = library.Songs;
     Song song = songs[0];
     MediaPlayer.Play(song);
}
```

For your second problem, did you copy the artwork over as well as the code and references? Some samples, other than the one you've downloaded include [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd231914.aspx) and [this](http://create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/windows_phone_music_manager). The [MediaPlayer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.mediaplayer_members.aspx) isn't a particularly complex class, it has the basic play, stop, pause etc.. methods. The second sample link provides a music manager that demonstrates how to handle certain events (such as a phone call) when using the `MediaPlayer`.

Comment: Hmm, I searching for something like is is [this application](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-GB/apps/8a16c2ee-16e1-43f0-9acd-d5fda84bbd40) when you click "play music" form appbar. There is a list of albums and playlist. I want to have something like this but but with list of songs, artist, album, playlists, genres etc, there is a method for do this ?
Second problem, yes i copied everything with images, references and all code, it's very weird.  Thank for your help.

Comment: Yes, the MediaLibrary I linked to. Click on the link and you'll see example code for getting songs. You'll also see the methods and properties for getting artists, albums playlists and genres. There's no one method for getting everything if that's what you're looking for. You have to get the properties individually using the methods provided.

Comment: @JohnCE - I found this article which should help http://www.dotnetspeaks.com/DisplayArticle.aspx?ID=164 :)

Answer (score 1):

John, I don't know if you solved the trouble, but i noticed when I put this code together that the `PopulateSongMetadata()` method was never actually called. This is what you are probably missing. Make sure `PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded` is actually loaded. Ensure this in your Page's xaml file by adding `Loaded="PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded"` to the page's

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code example I'm using to display the cover art for the currently playing song:

```
BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
                image.SetSource(MediaPlayer.Queue.ActiveSong.Album.GetAlbumArt());
```