# JumpList? Access to library

Tags: windows-phone-7

It is possible get access o [library list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MphAc.jpg) and play songs in my app ? Not like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8766491/how-to-get-a-list-of-songs-artists-albums-on-wp7-devices)

if not... how to do this JumpList? I can't find good sample code, ([this](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2011/01/a-windows-phone-7-jump-list-control/) is ugly and doesn't work correctly).

his JumpList is a special ListBox? Am I right? How to relay which song was selected?

Answer (score 1):

Ya earlier before August 2011, new Silverlight toolkit for WP7.1 mango  it was a special ListBox with code logic to position the main list items.

But in Latest toolkit it is provided as a control, if you use

> LongListSelector in your .xaml to show the list of items then it gives you a jumplist element as part of control.

[For more information and sample on the LongListSelector refer this link.](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/wp7-longlistselector-in-depth--part1-visual-structure-and-api)

you can [download silverlight toolkit from here](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/)

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you know, it's possible to get access to music library list?

Comment: Actually you can access the MediaLibrary as following  MediaLibrary ml = new MediaLibrary();

        SongCollection cl = ml.Songs;

        ArtistCollection artist = ml.Artists;

        AlbumCollection albums = ml.Albums;

        foreach (Album album in albums)
     {
                    //access the album related data here
                    string albumArtist = album.Artist.Name;

   
     } also for more information use this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.media.medialibrary.aspx